# Leave-One-Out Property (LOOP)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I was reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06222), and I was looking at the leave-one-out property that they mention in Appendix B.

The property is as follows:

For $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $x_i$ to be the $i$th element of $x$ and $x^{i\to 0}= (x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},0,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)$, replacing the $i$th element with zero.
A function $f: [0,1]^n\to[0,\infty)$ satisfies the leave-one-out-property (LOOP) if for any $i$ for $P\in [0,1]^n$, we have $f(P^{i\to 0})>0$ and

1. if $P_i\le f(P)$, then $P_i\le f(P^{i\to 0})=f(P)$.
2. if $P_i>f(P)$, then $P_i> f(P^{i\to 0})$.

I was having trouble understanding intuitively what this LOOP property entails as well as any applicable examples of functions with the LOOP property in practice.

Additionally, any advice on how to tackle this form of a question in the future is greatly appreciated!